# How to translate "开口呼、齐齿呼、合口呼、撮口呼" to English?

Tags: pinyin, pronounciation

How to translate "开口呼、齐齿呼、合口呼、撮口呼" to English?

开口呼、齐齿呼、合口呼、撮口呼 (四呼) are concepts of Chinese pronouonciation.

开口呼 - There is no glide before the nucleus vowel, such as "Ma4Ma4" (妈妈).

齐齿呼 - The glide is /i/, such as "Tian1" (天).

合口呼 - The glide is /u/, such as "Tuan2" (团).

撮口呼 - The glide is /ü/, such as "Jun1" (军).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is difficult to translate Four Hu into English. The content in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_hu) explains 'Four Hu' in English. I hope it will help you.